# R&D: Google Assistant in third party application

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk

I'm working on some shopping application,named as MyShopping. I would like to launch my application when user says launch MyShopping to Google assistant.

Is it possible to do? Could any one please help me

Comment: Have you seen: https://developers.google.com/actions/discovery/#app_invocation

Comment: Can you clarify - I assume by "App" in this case you mean an Android app, as opposed to an Action through the assistant itself?

Comment: @MorrisonChang in that link they provide option to start intent which created in the API.ai or action SDK . but there is no examples/guide to find way to invoke installed application .

Comment: For example if you say "send message using whatsApp" it prompt with to address and message once you confirm sending it will open your whats app

Comment: What you just described "send message using whatsApp" is specific to the Google search app (or Google Now): See section `More apps you can use with "Ok Google"` in https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/2940021?hl=en So only certain apps get direct voice commands. You are asking about Google Assistant which from what I can tell must start with "Talk/Speak to $action_app_name"

Comment: @Prisoner yes. App i meant android app. I have an android application named as "Shopping App", and it should be launched when user says "Launch Shopping App" or "Open Shopping App". Would like to know how to implement this